# color stuck in grayscale in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to apply colors to parts of font.

The problem is with the letter 'p' here

[image: screenshot]

I converted the letter to a vector shape with 'Create Outlines' and then cut it using the knife. I just can't get rid of the grayscale there.

For the letter 'a' I made a clipping mask, but the overlay is not accurate so I don't want to use that method.

Comment: I'm afraid there's really not enough information here to help. Check the **Color** panel to ensure the color is actually color.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the shape and then Edit -> Edit Colors -> Convert to CMYK

Comment: thank you!! that was exactly it. The Color panel was stuck in grayscale, and the steps suggested by SZCZERZO worked exactly.